# Best approach for populating model object(s) from a joined query?

Tags: model-view-controller, model

I'm building a small financial system.  Because of double-entry accounting, transactions always come in batches of two or more, so I've got a `batch` table and a `transaction` table.  (The transaction table has `batch_id`, `account_id`, and `amount` fields, and shared data like `date` and `description` are relegated to the `batch` table).

I've been using basic vo-type models for each table so far.  Because of this table structure, though, transactions will almost always be selected with a join on the `batch` table.

So should I take the selected records and splice them into two separate vo objects, or should I create a "shared" vo that contains both batch and transaction data?

There are a few cases in which `batch` records and/or `transaction` records are loaded individually, so they will each also have their associated vo class.  Are there possible pitfalls down the road if I have "overlapping" vo classes like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to tie models not to database tables, but to your views. E.g. if view has date field, then use "shared " view object (ideally even specific-to-the-view object), if view has only transaction info, use another object etc. It can be tedious, but separation of concerns will be worthy. Too much duplication can be remedied with reusing/inheriting when appropriate.

Comment: Do you mean "view" in the database sense, or something else?

Comment: "View" in a MVC sense. E.g. form, page etc.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  I had my head stuck in the data access layer.  Thanks!